A little Emoji puzzle #2
Can you place the emojis in the correct order beside the correct ordinals and justify why you have done so? (You can use each cell only once)

1.
2.
3.
4.
5.
6.
7.

This isn't a perfect fit, but may of these emoji remind me of...

 Do, a deer , a female deer
 Re, a drop  of golden sun ☀️
 Mi, a name ️️♏️I call myself
 Fa, a long, long way ️--️ to run 
 So, a needle pulling thread 
 La, a note  to follow so
 Ti, a drink  with jam  and bread 

 That will bring us back  ⬆️ to do, oh, oh, oh


I've also struggled with the A, P and Scorpio sign... Can I suggest that your Jamaican flag probably belongs in a different (hopefully obvious) spot in Line 7 though...? (Also, I have A to B in the spot where you presently have this flag, and was using the up-arrow myself in line 3...) Not saying my thoughts are all correct, of course.

Very close but a little tweaking and you will have it!

Stiv is correct but only the up arrow needs to be somewhere else.

@Stiv good call on the jamaican flag, that's gotta be it! I have a new interpretation for scorpio and up-arrow which I think is better but still not a slam dunk. And the A and P... still not sure there either.

Close enough congratulations
